# Can I create a pool of token in DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

Can I create a pool of token in Django RestFrame ?

I want to create a pool of token, where I will have 'n' number of token. Later on I want to assign token to a user. How should I proceed ?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question **twice**? by token do you mean token authentication? [DRF- Token Authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat hello sir, Yes sir I mean token authentication only. I have refereed the documentation earlier. It states the process but I don't have question about the process, I have question regarding the concept.